# Iterate through multiple divs in python beautifulsoup, output to df then csv

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Trying to build a scraper/parser for my school's course catalog. The first step is to scrape the Coursicle database to a csv, but I can only get it to spit out the first row right now.

Here's a snippet of html I'm trying to parse:

```
<div class="card back" style="display: block;">
    <div class="addClass Back"> 
        <i class="fa clicky fa-star Back"></i> 
        <i class="fa clicky fa-star-o Back"></i>  
        <i class="clicky icon-info-sign"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="courseNumberBack">
        <span class="subject">ANTH</span> <span class="number">54</span>-<span class="section">001</span>
        <div class="smallCourseInfo">

            <span class="abbrevTitle">First-Year Seminar: The Indians' New Worlds: Southeastern Histories from 1200 to 1800</span> 

        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="faddedLine">

    <div class="courseNameBack"><div class="days">TuTh</div><br>

    <div class="smallCourseInfo"> <div class="instructor">Clara Scarry</div></div>

    <div class="time">3:30pm-4:45pm</div><br>
    <div class="smallCourseInfo"> <div class="building">Alumni 203 </div></div>


    <div class="genEds">HS US WB </div>


</div>
```

And here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
import itertools
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/Users/as9934/Desktop/schedule/wb.htm"), "lxml")

cardback = (soup.find('div', class_='card back'))
for courseNumberBack in cardback.find_all('div', class_='courseNumberBack'):
    for subject in courseNumberBack.find_all('span', class_='subject'):
        for subjects in subject: 
            print (subjects.string,",", end=' ')

    for number in courseNumberBack.find_all('span', class_='number'):
        for numbers in number:
            print (numbers.string,",", end=' ')

    for section in courseNumberBack.find_all('span', class_='section'):
        for sections in section:
            print(sections.string,",", end=' ')

    for abbrevTitle in courseNumberBack.find_all('span', class_='abbrevTitle'):
        for abbrevTitles in abbrevTitle:
            print(abbrevTitles.string,",", end=' ')


for courseNameBack in cardback.find_all('div', class_='courseNameBack'):
    for day in courseNameBack.find_all('div', class_='days'):
        for days in day: 
            print(days.string,",", end=' ')

    for instructor in courseNameBack.find_all('div', class_='instructor'):
        for instructors in instructor:
            print(instructors.string,",", end=' ')

    for time in courseNameBack.find_all('div', class_='time'):
        for times in time:
            print(times.string,",", end=' ')

    for building in courseNameBack.find_all('div', class_='building'):
        for buildings in building:
            print(buildings.string,",", end=' ')

    for genEd in courseNameBack.find_all('div', class_='genEds'):
        for genEds in genEd:
            print(genEds.string, end=' ')
```

I tried this:

```
cardback = (soup.find('div', class_='card back'))
result = dict(
    zip(
    [cardback.text for cardback in soup.select('span.subject')] , 
    [cardback.text for cardback in soup.select('span.number')] ,
    [cardback.text for cardback in soup.select('span.section')] , 
    [cardback.text for cardback in soup.select('span.abbrevTitle')] , 
    [cardback.text for carback in soup.select('div.days')] , 
    [cardback.text for carback in soup.select('div.instructor')] , 
    [cardback.text for carback in soup.select('div.time')] , 
    [cardback.text for carback in soup.select('div.building')] , 
    [cardback.text for carback in soup.select('div.genEds')] 
    )
    )
print(result)
```

But that returns this error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 9; 2 is required
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When using `print` in python, you have 2 special kw arguments: `end` and `sep`. `end` argument is exactly, what you need. It will look something like this

```
print(something.text, ',', end=' ')
```

Comment: This is great thank you! Code is updated above. It is still only printing the first row, however.

Comment: You messed up the naming a little bit. You have a loop like `for numbers in number` and print `number`, but not `numbers`

Comment: Like this? `cardback = (soup.find('div', class_='card back'))
for courseNumberBack in cardback.find_all('div', class_='courseNumberBack'):
    for subject in courseNumberBack.find_all('span', class_='subject'):
        for subjects in subject: 
            print (subjects.text,",", end=' ') 
...
` 
That returns:
'AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: I got the error to go away by changing .text to .string, but it still only prints the first result.

Comment: There is a missing closing tag for `<div class="courseNameBack">`, also classes are separated by ' ', so `card back` is 2 separate classes, so you should've used `card-back` or something like that. And inner loops like `for days in day` are redundant, just replace them with `print(day, ...)`. I don't see any problems with your code other than ones above, please describe, what you want to do in detail, so that i can help you